# Assigning Roles to Users When Registering

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a role called 'Customer', I wish to add users who register automatically to that role. At the moment I can only assign users to roles by using ASP.net Web Site Administration Tool. I'm using the default LogOn.aspx and Register.aspx files from Account folder in vb web profile.

I have seen that other users have used:

```
Dim uName As String = registrationWizard.UserName.ToString   
Roles.AddUserToRole(uName, "Customer")
```

I'm not sure exactly where this needs to go, or even if this would work?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I added the following code below the AccountController and it's worked.

```
Roles.AddUserToRole(model.UserName, "Customer")
```